# I can't export shared photos from Photos. Why not?

Tags: mac, icloud, photos, data-transfer

This seems like it should be the most basic of functions.

I have some shared photos in Photos. They were taken by someone else and shared with me on iCloud. I can see them all on my Mac.

But I cannot download them.

Why not?

It doesn't matter if I select one, many, all or none of them the Export option is greyed out. I've never seen it active at all! Ever! What is the point of it and why is this so hard? I've been searching all over for the answer.